# Add click event to JButton in gridlayout - JAVA

Tags: java, swing

UPDATE:

Thanks to some helpful people, the solution has been found.

I am now creating the buttons like below, and adding the event:

```
for(String s: new String[]{"7", "8", "9", "4", "5", "6", "1", "2","3", "0", ".", "=" }) {// change here, as per your need
                  JButton btn = new JButton(s);
                  numButtonPanel.add(btn);
                  btn.addActionListener(new EventListener());
                }
```

NOTE:

EventListener is a class that was created (scroll down to the answers and you can see the class there)

I am creating a calculator using the JAVA Swing libraries, I currently have numerical buttons inside a gridlayout.

My question is, given the below code, how would I add click events to my JButtons?

Example of my JButtons:

```
numButtonPanel.add(new JButton("8"));
    numButtonPanel.add(new JButton("9"));
    numButtonPanel.add(new JButton("4"));
    numButtonPanel.add(new JButton("5"));
    numButtonPanel.add(new JButton("6"));
```

As you can see, I am creating them within the gridlayout...I am not just adding already created JButtons.

If anyone could help, that would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: You should find an answer to this simply by googling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using loop:

```
for(String s: new String[]{"8", "9", "4", "5"}) {// change here, as per your need
  JButton btn = new JButton(s);
  numButtonPanel.add(btn);
  btn.addActionListener(new YourActionListener());//<-- change here, as per your need
}
```

Comment: Its the class implementing `ActionListener`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), they are self configured and self contained actions...

```
public class NumberAction extends AbstractAction {
    private int value;
    public NumberAction(int value) {
        put(NAME, Integer.toString(value));
    }     

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // Do some work here...
    }
}
```

Then simply apply them to the buttons

```
numButtonPanel.add(new JButton(new NumberAction(8)));
numButtonPanel.add(new JButton(new NumberAction(9)));
numButtonPanel.add(new JButton(new NumberAction(4)));
numButtonPanel.add(new JButton(new NumberAction(5)));
numButtonPanel.add(new JButton(new NumberAction(6)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a reference and add reference to your layout so that you can add action listener on your buttons later on like

```
JButton yourButton = new JButton("8")
```

and then add it to your panel

```
numButtonPanel.add(yourButton);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. But the problem is, if I adopt this strategy, I will then have to create 30+ buttons...which will just increase the size of the code significantly...and I do not know If I want to do that. Is this the only way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Create your listener class like this

```
class SampleActionListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

    }    
}
```

And add listener to button like below

```
   String buttonLabels = new String[]{"8", "9", "4", "5", "6"};
   for(String s:buttonLabels)
     JButton comp = new JButton(s);
     comp.addActionListener(new SampleActionListener());
     numButtonPanel.add(comp);
   }
```

Comment: Ah ok, so following this...I can now register clicks. But my problem is, is that I do not want to manually create 30+ buttons....is this the only way to do it?

Comment: Hey, thanks this has been a good solution and has worked for me. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you create object in this way you cannot get the reference of object anywhere in class. You need to create each object to perform some specific task. As I am sure your all buttons does not perform same operation. You should check the following code, it would help you.

Constructor or Initializing method would look like as follows:

```
public Class_name()     //in my case constructor
{
     JButton btn1 = new JButton("Print Hello");
     JButton btn2 = new JButton("Print Welcome");
     btn1.addActionListener((ActionEvent e)-> {
          System.out.print("Hello");
     });
     btn2.addActionListener((ActionEvent e)-> {
          System.out.println(" Welcome");
     });
}
```

As you can see the above each button perform different task. In your case if you didn't specify reference to your button you cannot make you buttons to perform different task.

To my above point I show you where you would gets stuck.
ActionPerformed Method for above code replacing the content inside by overridden method.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
        if(e.getSource()==btn1)      //here you cannot identify which object generated the event
        {
              System.out.print("Hello");
        }
        if(e.getSource()==btn2)      
        {
              System.out.println(" Welcome");
        }
}
```