# How to make class method wait for user input from gui

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a program with a gui and a different class named Search with a static method named paging().
This paging method retrieves some results and shows them using pagination,
so, it prints first e.x 10 results and then asks the user if he wants to continue to the next page, previous, quit or jump to a page.
I have buttons for previous, next page etc. on the gui, so I want the paging() method to wait until the user clicks a button.
What is the right way to do this?

```
public Gui extends JFrame{

JButton Next;
JButton Previous;
JTextField textField;

public static void Main(){
 
  }
}
```

---

```
public class Search(){
   public static void paging(){
        int results; // the results returned for the search 
        int itempsPerPage = 10;
        
        while(true){
            Console.WriteLine("Press (n)ext page, (p)revious page, 
                                (q)uit");
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                  new InputStreamReader(System.in));  
         String input = reader.readLine();
         if (input.charAt(0)=='q') {
                 stopSearch = true;
                 break;
         }
         if(input.charAt(0) == 'p'){
           // Go to previous page
             break;
         }
         else if(input.charAt(0) == 'n'){
            //Go to next page
             break;
            }  
         }
    }
}
```

This is how it was written initially as a console program

Comment: Do https://www.tutorialsfield.com/jbutton-click-event/  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26628033/add-click-event-to-jbutton-in-gridlayout-java answer your question?

Comment: Maybe for a better answer to this: Which framework are you using to implement the gui ?

Comment: It's a swing interface

Comment: @Reporter, the gui and paging() methods are on different classes

Comment: @blueberry123 Then provide example code. An individual problem needs an individual solution.

Comment: *I want the paging() method to wait until the user clicks a button.* - this is the default behaviour. A Swing GUI generally sits there and does nothing until the user generates some kind of event. So if you have some kind of looping logic in your paging method  you need to remove it. Your logic should just display 10 items and do nothing until the clicks on a button at which time you then invoke the appropriate logic.

Comment: yes, there is a loop that waits for user action. This program was initially written as a console program and at that point it would wait for user input from the console.

Comment: Maybe you should consider JavaFX. It has a [Pagination](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Pagination.html) control.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre].

Comment: Console and GUI applications are fundamentally different. In a console application, user input is something you go and get. In a GUI application, user input is something that happens to you. You need to turn things inside-out to go from one to the other.